# How to Print Specific Table with Data Filled in the input fields from Browser?

Tags: php, html

I have an application running on localhost!
There is a page for input students marks like 'Class Participation' , 'Midterm Exam' , 'Final Exam' , 'Marks Obtained', 'Points'

I just want to create a button to print this specific table with input fields filled!
These values are not coming from Database!

See the example table here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgqCV.jpg

Comment: what you have done so far?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. We don't want to write your code for you. Generally what happens here is you have a go at the problem (even if just planning out an algorithm), then put your work up here and tell us where you have gotten stuck. then we help you get past the point where you're stuck... and you finish it up. :)
So... have a go. When you're done, come back and *edit your question* and add the code or working-out... and tell us what you need to fix.

Comment: are you using jquery? If so, an easy solution is printThis() plugin https://github.com/jasonday/printThis

Comment: @Cory I want to print the 'Students Marks' Table filled with data!
on paper!

Comment: Right, which you can. printThis() allows you to send any given element on a web page to a printer. It avoids the problem of blocked popups, too

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="printsection"> your table</div>

<button class="btn btn-default" onClick="window.print();"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print</button>

<script language="javascript">
function printPage(printContent) 
{
var display_setting="toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,";
display_setting+="scrollbars=yes,width=800, height=600, left=200, top=100";
var printpage=window.open("","",display_setting);
printpage.document.open();
printpage.document.write('<html><head><title>Employee List</title></head>');
printpage.document.write('<body onLoad="self.print()">'+ printContent +'</body>  </html>');
printpage.document.close();
printpage.focus();
}
</script>
```